# Call property set function within class in Kotlin

Tags: class, object, kotlin, properties

I'd like for every time my class sets a property for it to call the set function for that property.

here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var text = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        //Do some other things
        ....
    }

...

fun someFunction() {
    ...
    //This should do everything in the set function, not just set the value
    text = "new text" 
    ...
}
```

I've tried doing `this.text = "new text"`, but that still just set the value of `text` to `new text`. Is there a way to call that set function from within my class, or do I have to create a separate `setText` function, like I would do in Java?

Comment: Calling `this.text = "new text"` *does* call the setter you've defined. How are you verifying that it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already call the setter. It just happens that you only call `field = value` inside it. Try using `println` function inside it and see that the setter is indeed called.

Comment: Please try log something to console.